# How to get the request parameters in `@Aspect`?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop

I was trying to add logs on every request to print IP, time, request parameters, response body, etc. Here is my code:

```
@Around("execution(* cn.dogchao.carcare.web.controller..*.*(..))")
public Object doAround(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    RequestAttributes ra = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    ServletRequestAttributes sra = (ServletRequestAttributes)ra;
    HttpServletRequest request = sra.getRequest();

    // always empty!
    inputParamMap = request.getParameterMap();
    // uri
    requestPath = request.getRequestURI();

    fromIP = getIpAddr(request);

    // 
    outputParamMap = new HashMap<>();
    Object result = pjp.proceed();// 
    outputParamMap.put("result", result);

    return result;
}
```

And I had a `Controller` like this:

```
@Controller("channelController")
@RequestMapping(value = "/channel")
public class ChannelController {
    @Autowired
    private ChannelService channelService;
    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/salesChannelAdd")
    public String salesChannelAdd(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
        ChannelVO vo;
        try {
            vo = JSON.parseObject(JSON.toJSON(params).toString(), ChannelVO.class);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return JSON.toJSONString(new ResultJson(ErrorCode.INVALID_PARAM, "参数异常:"+e.getCause()).getResultMap());
        }

        if(!vo.validate()){
            return JSON.toJSONString(new ResultJson(ErrorCode.INVALID_PARAM, vo.getErrorMsg()).getResultMap());
        }
        return JSON.toJSONString(channelService.createChannel(vo));
    }
}
```

Now I print everything except the params. I got a empty parameter map. I don't know why it's empty and how to get all the params.

Comment: Why so complex? Spring already has a filter for you which does all that no need to hack around with AOP for that. Use the right technology for it, a filter in this case.

Comment: @M.Deinum But I don't know how. Did you have the demo code?

Comment: @M.Deinum You mean `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter `?

Comment: Yes or the log4j one. But if you want to log all that information, then use a filter. Use the proper tool for the job.